# Why do some hotels show different available amenities in HOD than SOAP XML?

Tags: sabre

I've found that for at least one hotel amenity - Eco Friendly Certified - I don't appear to be finding any hotels where the HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ/HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ call is returning the correct data.  Here's an example hotel (0023585):

```
>HOD0023585
** DOUBLE CLICK ON HOTEL NAME FOR MAPS AND PHOTOS **            
LX0023585 LEFAY RESORT SPA LAGO DI GARDA    VRN                 
ADDR-     VIA FELTRINELLI 136                                   
          GARGNANO IT 25084                 LAKE GARDA          
[...]
PROPERTY INFORMATION                                            
[...]
ADAA  -N-    FSPA  -Y-    ADLT  -N-    ECOH  -Y-
```

Note that it has a `Y` for `ECOH`. It also shows the hotel if you do an availability request requiring that flag to be set.

Yet when I issue the HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ request for it, here is the relevant section of the response:

```
<HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.1.0">
  <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
    <stl:Success timeStamp="2019-02-27T09:20:30-06:00" />
  </stl:ApplicationResults>
  <RoomStay>
    <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="LX" GeoConfidenceLevel="0" HotelCityCode="VRN" HotelCode="0023585" HotelName="LEFAY RESORT SPA LAGO DI GARDA" Latitude="45.687153" Longitude="10.643102" NumFloors="2" RPH="001">
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>VIA FELTRINELLI 136</AddressLine>
        <AddressLine>GARGNANO IT 25084</AddressLine>
        <CountryCode>IT</CountryCode>
      </Address>
[...]
      <PropertyOptionInfo>
[...]
        <EcoCertified Ind="false" />
```

I have not been able to find a single hotel where `EcoCertified` is actually set to `true`.

Is this something that's actually controlled in two different places on the back end (a setting for ECOH in cryptic and a setting for EcoCertified in XML)? Or am I somehow doing something wrong?